# How to add leading zero to select rows of a column of integers in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, leading-zero, merging-data

I've hit a problem which I'm assuming needs an easy solution, but I've been going in circles trying to figure it out with no luck.

I have two dfs, each with a "Facility.ID" column. In df1, Facility.IDs range from 5 integer digits to 6 integer digits. In df2, all IDs are 6 integer digits, where 0's were placed in front of the previously 5 integer digits to make them all 6 digits (For example, one Facility.ID in df1 is 10001, but in df2 the same site's is 010001).

I need to merge these two dfs by their common Facility.ID column, but df1 lacks 0s for the first 536 rows of Facility.IDs. These are expressed as integers in my df, not characters.

For context:

- The same Facility is referenced as 10001 in df1, but 010001 in df2. I essentially just need to add a 0 in front of the first 536 Facility.ID's of df1 to merge the two dfs correctly.

Tried using sprintf, but ran into an error code that made it seem like I should convert the column to be characters instead of integers. Though it didn't work.

> final2019 <- transform(final2019,
> Facility.ID = as.character(Facility.ID)) %>%
> sprintf("%06d", final2019$Facility.ID)

Error in sprintf(., "%06d", final2019$Facility.ID) :
'fmt' is not a character vector

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Your command looks off. It should be more like `Facility.ID = as.character(Facility.ID)) %>% sprintf("%06d", .)` or just `Facility.ID = sprintf("%06d", as.character(Facility.ID)))` What command are you actually using to do the join?

Answer (score 0):

Up front: two problems here:

- the *known* problem is that `%>%` is passing the return value from `transform` as the first argument to `sprintf`; in this case, it's passing a `data.frame` to a function that expects a length-1 string; and
- even once we fix that, the `sprintf` format won't work.

Follow through to the end ... I walk you through it a little, then wrap up with a likely-correct and more efficient solution.

---

`transform` passes a `data.frame` to the next function in the pipe, so try

```r
final2019 <- transform(final2019, Facility.ID = as.character(Facility.ID)) %>% 
  transform(Facility.ID = sprintf("%06d", Facility.ID))
```

In your case, the way `%>%` works is that it prepends the current frame as the first argument of the next function. In your case, that means the flow looked somewhat like this:

```r
tmp1 <- transform(final2019, Facility.ID = as.character(Facility.ID))
sprintf(fmt = tmp1, "%06d", final2019$Facility.ID)
```

(I added the `fmt=` there to identify that the first argument will be passed the frame.)

where `fmt` is supposed to be

```
     fmt: a character vector of format strings, each of up to 8192
          bytes.
```

Clearly this is not what you wanted/intended.

Even if you explicitly name `fmt="%06d"`, the frame will then be the first *unnamed* argument, which is going to erro with `unsupported type`, since `sprintf` mostly works on "simple" things, not lists/frames, etc.

---

Heads up, though, you're still in trouble: `%06d` expects an integer, not a string, so you're still going to err ... while this is unrelated to the `%>%`-mixup, it's still something to resolve:

```r
final2019 <- transform(final2019, 
  Facility.ID = sprintf("%06s", as.integer(as.character(Facility.ID)))
```

You need *both* `as.integer(as.character(.))`, though, since on a factor, `as.integer` alone will return the underlying index integers, not the strings to which they refer. And *that* is a really confusing problem to troubleshoot:

```r
vec <- factor(c("1","3","22"))
as.integer(vec)
# [1] 1 3 2
as.integer(as.character(vec))
# [1]  1  3 22
```

Answer (score -1):

You can transform the vector with regex:

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Facility.ID = 
  # if the number of `d`igits is < 6, ...
  ifelse(str_count(as.character(Facility.ID),"\\d") < 6,
                              # ... add leading 0: 
                              str_c("0", Facility.ID),
                              # else leave as is:
                              Facility.ID))
  Facility.ID
1      011111
2      022222
3      333333
4      044444
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Facility.ID = c(11111,22222,333333,44444)
)
```